# Compare two dataframes and only keep certain rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I've been searching over google and stackoverflow for a while for this basic question. I tried multiple solutions including `pd.merge` but it fails to do what I'm looking for.

I have two dataframes:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'col2': [1, 3, 4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A', 'D', 'E', 'F'], 'col2': [2, 5, 6, 7]})
```

I would like to compare the two dataframes and to keep only the rows 'D', 'E', 'F' of the second dataframe by only taking into account the values of 'col1'.

Could you tell me how to do that ?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: What's the logic?

Comment: It's a toy example but the idea is to compare them. It would be "like" a right join without the intersection part. I know how to do that in SQL but not in Python

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like you want to use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and reverse the output with `~` for [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
out = df2[~df2['col1'].isin(df1['col1'])]
```

Note that you can achieve this with [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) although it's a bit convoluted:

```
out = (df2.merge(df1['col1'], how='left', indicator=True)
          .loc[lambda d: d.pop('_merge').eq('left_only')]
       )
```

Output:

```
  col1  col2
1    D     5
2    E     6
3    F     7
```